# If $f$ is an entire function and $f^{(n)} = 0$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$, then is a polynomial of degree no more than $n-1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, polynomials

I'm looking for a proof of the given theorem, but I'm having some trouble with the inductive step in an induction proof. I was wondering if anyone would be willing to lend me a hand. Here's the theorem and my attempt at a proof:

> Theorem: If $f$ is an entire function and $f^{(n)} = 0$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$, then is a polynomial of degree no more than $n-1$.
>
> Proof: In order to do this proof, we will proceed by induction. Consider the base case $f^{(n)} = f^{(n-1)\prime}$. From class, we now know that $f^{(n-1)} = C$ since $f^{(n)} = 0$, where $C \in \mathbb C$ (Note the polynomial has degree 0). We now proceed with the inductive step. Let us assume that $f^{(k)}(z) = a_1 + a_2z + \ldots + a_{n-k}z^{n-k-1}$.

I was about to proceed by showing that the derivative is unique then showing that a polynomial of higher degree fulfills it, but that seemed like a lot of work. Anyone have some ideas for a possibly simpler proof where I don't have to struggle with the inductive step?

Comment: Use Taylor formula

Answer (score 1):

If $f^{(n)}(z)=0$ for all $z$, then from Cauchy's Integral Formula we see that

$$f^{(n+1)}(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{f^{(n)}(z')}{(z'-z)}\,dz'=0$$

for all $z$ enclosed by $C$.

Letting the radius of the circular contour $C$ approach $\infty$, we deduce that $f^{(n+1)}(z)=0$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$.  Continuing, we find that $f^{(p)}(z)=0$ for all $p\ge n$.

Therefore, using the series representation for $f(z)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
f(z)&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}z^k\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}z^k\\\\
\end{align}$$

which is indeed a polynomial of degree $n-1$ as was to be shown.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark